# Laravel 5.2 : Adding Auth module in pingpong

Tags: laravel-5

How to add 'Default Laravel Auth Module' to pingpong module folder?

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Above commands will create auth controller/module in default http folder. But I'm using pingpong component to create modules in my project. So, i want to move auth controller to pingpong module folder. Is there any command from pingpong to install auth directly in pingpong module folder

Comment: still pingpong fully supported to Laravel 5.1 any way you want add auth folder to your modules  use  " php artisan module:make auth " command

Comment: @SarangaR  'php artisan module:make auth' it will create a module which name is auth. But i need entire auth controller and functions [mean default laravels auth controller and functionality]

Comment: First you have to create auth module and then add all laravel default auth controller to that(http folder). then change your Route inside auth module. I have done before

Comment: @SarangaR totally new for laravel . m getting error "Class Modules\Auth\Http\Controllers\AuthController does not exist" . so in route what should i add

Comment: first you should check carefully namespase, use classes then in your route.php in auth module add Route::get('/', 'Modules\Auth\Http\Controllers\AuthController@getLogin'); Note: sometimes you have to do more go step by step cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can make Controllers and blade-templates manually.
Use the custom auth.php config with the

```
    'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'admin',
    'passwords' => 'admins',
],
    'guards' => [
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
    'providers' => [
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => Modules\Admin\Models\Admin::class,
    ],

],
'passwords' => [
    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'email' => 'admin::auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```

But in this case you need to create the custom middleware with

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    foreach(['auth','database','database.connections','admin'] as $key) {
        $config = Config::get($key, []);
        $path = __DIR__.'/../../Config/' . preg_replace('/\W/i','_',$key) . '.php';
        Config::set($key, array_merge($config, require $path));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

This code merges the global config with your custom config cripts (any options, database connections and etc.)

Create templates and login forms. You can use 'admin::auth.emails.password' for including templates from othe rmodules.
Moreover, you can use

```
protected $guard = 'admin';
protected $loginView = 'admin::auth.login';
protected $registerView = 'admin::auth.register';
```

in the Modules\Admin\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController and

```
protected $redirectTo = '/admin';
protected $linkRequestView = 'admin::auth.passwords.email';
protected $resetView = 'admin::auth.passwords.reset';
```

in the Modules\Admin\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController .